# Using window.history.replaceState() to effectively delete page history

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page that should only be accessible *after* another page. So say, when traversing the site, you visit **Before** > **After** > **Other** pages. If the user were to press *Back* in their browser, they would be taken to **After**, which is obviously undesirable.

My first attempt at a solution would be to manipulate the browser's history. I know we can't delete a page in history, but I figured if I changed the **After** history entry to **Before**, that would be good enough.

```
window.history.replaceState({},'','before.php');
```

But it doesn't work. Instead, does this:

Traverse **Before**, **After**, **Other**... and as I *Back* through history...

- Loads **After** (url is **Before#**)
- Loads **After** (url is **Before**)
- Loads **Before**

Answer (score 0):

How about inside your After page, when going to Other, use `location.replace()`.

### After.html

`<a href="other.htm" onclick="location.replace(this.href);return false;">go</a>`

Comment: But I would have to include that on every link on the page! (There's a navigation bar along the top.) Thanks for the suggestion, it's nice to have options. But I'm hoping for a more graceful solution.